# Time travel future (with calculations)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, time, time-dilation

First, I have seen a few similar questions, but none involved the formulas and calculations I want to find. This is why I do not consider this as a duplicate.

I know time travel to the future is possible, but I also know that I cannot use the special relativity formulas if there is a change of speed. I need G.R. but I do not know any.

This is my question:

> At time $t=0$ (for me and the fixed referential), I start to travel on a straight line away from the origin ($x=0$). Let's assume that, in the fixed referential of the origin (time=t), my travel lasts 1 unit (I come back at $t=1$ unit of time) my position is given by $x(t)=(3c\sqrt3)t^2(1-t)^2$. The letter $c$ stands for the speed of light in vacuum in the appropriate unit. (If the units are a problem, let's consider I divide this whole thing with $t_0^3$ where $t_0=1$ unit).
>
> What is the time difference between my watch and a fixed watch that was resting at the origin when I come back?

I do not expect anyone to derive this for me (but I you feel like it, I would be happy), but can you indicate to me which formula I should use? Or, if it is too complicated, maybe try to give me an order of magnitude and how you got it? I would really appreciate it.

PS: The reason why I took that function is because I wanted to have a speed of 0 at the start and at the end, and wanted a max speed close to 3/4 of $c$.

PPS: I originally wanted to use the Lorentz transform, but I was told those cannot be used because of the u-turn in my example.

Comment: You are looking for the (Lorentzian) arclength of the curve $t\mapsto(t,x(t))$, which you can get by integrating.  (This is not a general relativity problem.)

Comment: Oh, I thought that GR was mandatory when the acceleration was not 0. Otherwise you end up with the twin paradox.

Comment: "*I know time travel to the future is possible*" Quite a statement. Slowing time down is not the same as traveling to *the future*.

Comment: @Steeven It was a short way of saying it. And to me, it is the same, I mean when they do experiments with atomic clocks rotating around earth at high speed, there is a time difference ;)

Comment: @WillO Can you confirm with a reference that you can use Lorentz transformations for a non-Galilean referential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calculation is easy if we do it from the perspective of the stationary observer. Suppose I'm sitting on Earth watching you zooming about on your rocket. In my rest frame I identify spacetime points using my coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ i.e. the time as measured by my clock and the distances measured with my ruler.

Let's suppose you're moving along my $x$ axis i.e. directly towards or away from me, as this makes the algebra simpler. Now suppose I observe you to move a distance $dx$ in a time $dt$, then the corresponding elapsed time on your clock, $d\tau$ is given by this equation:

$$ c^2d\tau^2 = c^2dt^2 - dx^2 \tag{1} $$

This equation is called the Minkowski metric and it is the equation describing the geometry of flat spacetime.

Anyhow, to calculate your elapsed time I note that $dx/dt$ is just your velocity $v$ as measured in my coordinates, so that means $dx=vdt$. If I substitute for $dx$ in equation (1) I get:

$$ c^2d\tau^2 = c^2dt^2 - v^2dt^2 $$

And a bit of rearranging gives:

$$ d\tau = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\,dt $$

Your velocity is a function of time, $v(t)$, because you start next to me, accelerate away then stop and head back. And if I know the form of this function $v(t)$ all I have to do is calculate the integral:

$$ \tau = \int_0^t \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2(t)}{c^2}}\,dt \tag{2} $$

And the value $\tau$ is your elapsed time. Note that for any $v \ne 0$ the quantity $1-v^2(t)/c^2 \lt 1$ so when we integrate this we will inevitably find that $\tau \lt t$ i.e. less time has passed for you than for me so you have experienced time dilation.

You say in your question that your equation of motion is:

$$ x(t)=(3c\sqrt3)t^2(1-t)^2 $$

And I assume the $x$ and $t$ are distance in time in my coordinates since in your rest frame obviously you aren't moving. So just differentiate this equation to get $v(t)$ then substitute it into equation (2) and do the integral. That will tell you how far into the future you have travelled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer! (and that confirms what you had said WillO).